# Finding 9-digit Positive Integers with Specific Decimal Digits that are Divisible by a Specific number

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, integers

Ola,

A positive integer $Q$ is $lovely$ if all its decimal digits are 6 or 9.

Find all nine-digit $lovely$ numbers which are divisible by 300.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. It is a good habit to provide context or show what you've tried when asking a question.

Comment: Hint:  you already have.  Why is this so?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If $300$ divides a number, so does $100$. What must the ``ones" digit of such a number be?

Comment: 0 perhaps? But I still don't get how that's useful...

Comment: Is $0$ either $6$ or $9$?

Comment: But if it was either 6 or 9, then it wouldn't be divisible by 300 right...?